# jQuery - How to position, resize and move one image over another

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- to position one image over another and be able to move it within the region of the containing image
- to be able to resize the top image, by keeping its ratio
- to know the size `(w, h)` and position `(x, y)` of the top image within the containing image container

What I want is actually something like jCrop, but the highlight region needs to be a png image, and not a semitransparent rectangle.

Comment: Where your idea /code.. stackover is not a place to provide the code for you

Comment: i recommend reading article like the following. There're couple of pretty good scripts for cropping purposes. I think you will find the one suits you best. Here's a [link](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/javascript-image-cropping-scripts/) UPD: i got it, you need and image instead of rectangle. Perhaps you will need to modify one of those plugin.

Comment: Devtrix, thank you for your response. I'll take a look at those plugins. I didn't provide any code, because I was just looking for an idea of what to use and how to do it, if possible.